# I have enabled V8 runtime, but I get an error trying save: "We're Sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Tags: google-apps-script, server-error

I'm getting the

> "We're Sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

when trying to save the script

If I run the script as is, it runs an older version

Here's my code:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet2.getRange("D3:D6");
  cell.setValue("Out");
  var cell = sheet2.getRange("D8:D12");
  cell.setValue("Out");
  var cell = sheet2.getRange("D14:D17");
  cell.setValue("Out");
  var cell = sheet2.getRange("D19:D31");
  cell.setValue("Out");
  var cell = sheet2.getRange("D33:D42");
  cell.setValue("Out");
  var cell = sheet2.getRange("D44:D50");
  cell.setValue("Out");
}
```

Comment: Try removing any protections in your sheet.

Comment: the "older code" runs fine, so I don't think anything is wrong with the sheet.

Comment: Quick solution: Disable V8. If you need further help please add a brief descripiton of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Also include enough details to reproduce the problem as well about the expected results..

Comment: Tried to disable and I get the same "We're sorry ..." error.  I've been getting this error for a few weeks now

Comment: I got it figured out.  I deleted the whole project and copy/pasted the same code into a new one (added the appropriate triggers) and I'm getting no errors now.

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out. I deleted the whole project and copy/pasted the same code into a new one (added the appropriate triggers) and I'm getting no errors now.